# NetBeans : diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5 (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)

Tags: java, netbeans

I don't know why when I code:

```
List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

it said that

```
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

I already use JDK 1.7. When I opened it in eclipse, I didn't get that error.

Comment: Maybe you are using Maven? Java 1.5 is the default for Maven. You have to explicitely configure the compiler to use Java 7.

Comment: <> represents generics .. if u need java 1.5 stick with List a; if you can get 1.7 jump to List<String> a;

Comment: My project had sub-projects, and while the main project used JDK 11 set. The source/binary format of the sub-projects were defaulted to 1.5. 

The fix for me was actually Opening the sub-projects, which then updated the source/binary format to match the parent project (JDK 11).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`-source 1.5` means your code will be compatible with Java version 1.5 and cannot use language constructs introduced later. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javac.html to find more.

Easy way to achieve what you want (to be able to use diamond operator added in Java 7) is to update project source/binary version in project customizer - go to `Projects` tab (Ctrl-1), select project node, choose `Properties` in its context menu and update `Source/Binary Format` field in Source tab.

Answer (score 4):

You missed this:

List<**String**> data = new ArrayList<**String**>();

You have to put "String" in both "<>"

Answer (score 4):

right click and choose Properties follow this picture and select new version of source
[image]

Comment: this picture suported to "Radim"